# how to expose Domain Controller on public IP address, and make other DC talk to it?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

basically we have 2 DC servers which used to have site-2-site VPN but it's not working anymore. So we started to get various errors, DNS stopped working, etc, etc. As a last resort attempt (before manually demoting one of the DCs), i want to "connect" them via public IP - so I can, at least, do a clean demote. But I can't figure out what I need to do for this. Both servers have 2 NICs, one with internal and one with external IP.

how should I point one DC to replicate with another one over public IP?

Comment: I would fix the VPN before exposing the servers to the web.

Comment: already wasted about a week of time on fixing VPN :( I don't want to keep servers exposed for any extended period of time - just to be able to demote one DC.

Comment: You could use a simple VPN like Hamachi.  Running a DC over the internet could be problematic, even in the short term, if either ISP is blocking SMB, RPC, or any of the other protocols which happen to overlap between virus propagation and DC replication.

Comment: hold on: DC1 (which is failing) does have VPN access to DC2. But I can't establish access from DC2 to DC1 - so will installing Hamachi on DC2 help me to get things working properly?

Answer (score -1):

DC's use DNS.

Now, you hook up both sides with the public IP, THen go into the DNS on both sides and start working through all relevant entries so that the IP-Addresses match up. Right now they do not see each other and think that the other side is on another IP, which makes any sync hard.

Not sure which entries you will need to fix up for things to start working again - "all relevant". May be as simple as the IN A entries for the names on both sides, so they can ping each other.